# Where include this params?

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

I used Framework7 + Vue.js and where include this params:

`showBarsOnPageScrollEnd: false`

I include in app init. but don't work this

Answer (score 0):

Framework7 documentation shows an example on how to include Navbar parameters (not Vue specific):

```
// if you use it on navbars:
var app = new Framework7({
  navbar: {
    hideOnPageScroll: true,
    iosCenterTitle: false,
    // added by me, not in the documentation
    showOnPageScrollEnd: false,
  },
});

// if you use it on toolbars:
var app = new Framework7({
  toolbar: {
    hideOnPageScroll: true,
    // added by me, not in the documentation
    showOnPageScrollEnd: false,
  },
});
```

The link to the documentation: https://framework7.io/docs/navbar.html

Please note, that the property you use **showBarsOnPageScrollEnd** is not in the documentation - probably it's deprecated.